# What is the equivalent of Pip (Python) in Swift 3?

Tags: swift

I have just started learning Swift 3 after finished with Python and i dont know how to download existing Swift libraries. Is it similar to using Pip in Python ?

Comment: You can use *Cocoapods* or *Carthage* to manage your dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

So there are three options for downloading external libraries in Swift

1. Cocoapods: http://cocoapods.org
2. Carthage:https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage
3. Swift Package Manager: https://swift.org/package-manager/